# How can I list user roles in new line in datatables and laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

I'm working with laravel 8 and datatables, I'm listing data of registered users in my application, everything is working fine, but I have a column named roles where I want to list all the roles that are associated to a user,
I can get the roles this way:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2o6i.png)

But what I want is to show roles like this:

- Role 1
- Role 2
- Role 3

This is the code in my controller

```
//Getting users with the name of associated roles 
    $users = User::with('roles')->get();
    $users = $users->transform(function($item){
        $item->role_names = $item->roles->pluck('name')->implode(' ');
        return $item;
    })->all();
```

I'm using implode method to separate the data, I've tried using this to display the info in a new line, but it doesn't work

```
->implode('<br>');
```

This is how I'm rendering the datatable in my js file:

```
        "columns" : [
            {data : 'id' , className : 'id'},
            {data : 'name', className : 'name'},
            {data : 'email', className : 'email'},
            {data : 'role_names', className : 'roles'},
            {data : 'status', className : 'status'},
            {data : 'actions', className : 'actions'},
        ]
```

Any idea? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using your controller to modify the appearance of data, that is the job of the view. In this case, you can use the Datatables [`column.render` function](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) to format the data how you desire using a callback function, something like this:

```js
$('#example').dataTable({
    "columns" : [
        {data : 'id' , className : 'id'},
        {data : 'name', className : 'name'},
        {data : 'email', className : 'email'},
        {data : 'roles', className : 'roles', render: function(data) {
            // data is your array of roles, do what you like with it
            let names = data.map(x => x.name);
            return names.join("<br/>");
            
        }},
        {data : 'status', className : 'status'},
        {data : 'actions', className : 'actions'},
    ]
});
```

Comment: It works perfectly, I modified a little bit the data.map() method to show the data inside a bootstrap badge and pass it to a  details modal in my view